# Cannot update entity column with the same value

Tags: go, go-gorm

This is a very small program. It goes like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    Id    int64  `gorm:"PRIMARY_KEY;AUTO_INCREMENT"` 
    Name  string `gorm:"size:32;not null"`           
    Email string `gorm:"size:128;not null"`          
}

func main() {
    
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root@tcp(localhost:3306)/test_db?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    
    db.Create(&User{
        Name:  "Max",
        Email: "maxluan@gmail.com",
    })

    var user User
    db.Where("name = ?", "Max").First(&user)
    fmt.Println("Max's email：" + user.Email)

    // Update and save
    user.Email = "maxluan2@gmail.com"
    db.Save(user)

    defer db.Close()
}
```

When I first run the program. It works just fine. It creates the record, and updates its email column. Then I removed the *create* section and run the program again. I expect it to fetch the user, assign the same value to email column and save. Nothing is supposed to change. But the program panicked.

```
panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value [recovered]
        panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.(*Scope).callCallbacks.func1(0xc000234300)
        /home/shiyanlou/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/scope.go:865 +0xb0
panic(0x6f6860, 0x7a5720)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x175
reflect.Value.Addr(0x727200, 0xc000226570, 0x99, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:270 +0x85
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.queryCallback(0xc000234300)
        /home/shiyanlou/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/callback_query.go:84 +0x47b
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.(*Scope).callCallbacks(0xc000234300, 0xc0001de420, 0x3, 0x4, 0x0)
        /home/shiyanlou/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/scope.go:869 +0x83
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.(*DB).First(0xc000229520, 0x727200, 0xc000226570, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7b24a0)
        /home/shiyanlou/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:334 +0x125
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.(*DB).FirstOrCreate(0xc000229520, 0x727200, 0xc000226570, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00011df40)
        /home/shiyanlou/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:428 +0xa5
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.(*DB).Save(0xc0001f21a0, 0x727200, 0xc000226570, 0xc000226570)
        /home/shiyanlou/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:473 +0x1bb
main.main()
        /home/project/main.go:28 +0x287
exit status 2
```

Please help explain why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try `db.Save(&user)`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Riwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4317297/riwen)

According to [gorm doc](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html), when calling `save`, we should pass in the reference.

`db.Save(&user)` would work.

This is a low level mistake. To avoid such mistakes, one should always read doc more carefully, pay special attention to value vs. reference.